# Auto generate pkpass file and send to wallet Iphone

Tags: php, ios, laravel, wallet

I would like to generate `pkpass` files on my server automatically and send them to users in an email.

According to [Apple's Wallet Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1), I should use signpass tool to generate pkpass file. Can I install this on server (Debian) and auto generate pkpass for our Guests after they submit a new order? If it isn't possible - how can I auto generate pkpass files and attach to E-mail confirmation with php Laravel?

I don't want to use external tools like passsource.com.

Comment: Improved grammar and wording, added relevant tags.

Comment: Did it work with you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, it's very simple to implement and works properly:

https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass

You might need to change the code a bit, that is, generate the .pkpass file, save on local, send via email and delete. Repeat the number of times that you want.

Comment: Pal, you would get more upvotes if you include some **code** to show how to use the library, it's never too late to do it , just click on **Edit** to update your answer, it will be more helpful for people.